# Display gridview value into textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm not able to display the selected gridview row's column data into the textbox.
I have a select column at my gridview. The selected row to be displayed is already declared as a string.

Code :

```
tbpolicereport.Text = GVStatusReportPolice.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
```

Update :

The above code is correct. This code is used when you bind your gridview with the sql server through the sqldatasource. the cell number is just the column number you would like to display out.

After debugging, i realized that the value did pass through however it wasn't able to be display out on my textfield. After re-creating the entire form, the value appears magically.

Comment: what is the issue? are you not getting any data as selected row? where are you data binding?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the row and column indexes..
The Value can be taken like this:

```
int rowindex = GVStatusReportPolice.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
int columnindex= = GVStatusReportPolice.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex; 

lblCID.Text = GVStatusReportPolice.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I have a select column in my gridview where when i clicked the select button, it will highlight the specific row i have selected. Hence i'm wondering how do i transfer the specific gridview value of the highlighted row. Therefore, i reckon i do not need to specify the row index.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
tbpolicereport.Text = GVStatusReportPolice.Currentcell.Value;
```